# Knapsack Algorithm: Why we use wt[i-1] instead of wt[i]

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem

Considering the following part of an implementation of Knapsack algorithm:

```
 // Build table K[][] in bottom up manner
for (i = 0; i <= n; i++)
{
    for (w = 0; w <= W; w++)
    {
        if (i == 0 || w == 0)
            K[i][w] = 0;
        else if (wt[i - 1] <= w)
            K[i][w]
                    = max(val[i - 1] + K[i - 1][w - wt[i - 1]], K[i - 1][w]);
        else
            K[i][w] = K[i - 1][w];
    }
}
```

I have a basic doubt why we use wt[i-1] while we are checking the ith element?

Comment: Array indices number up from 0, but we can choose to number items up from 0 or from 1.  In the latter case it makes sense to use `wt[i-1]` to record the weight of the i-th item, to avoid wasting the first space in the `wt[]` array.  But it makes sense to store the maximum value achievable by a subset of the first `i` items that use at most `w` weight in `K[i][w]` (and not, e.g., `K[i-1][w]`), since we *do* need to calculate the maximum value achievable for the empty set of items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first for loop runs `i=0; i<=n; i++` this means it will run n+1 iterations, while you have only n objects. This is OK, because i=0 is special cased to assign `K[i][w] = 0` so basically this will initialize the first row with 0s. Now that i=0 has a special meaning, the array is shifted by 1 (so i=1 refers to the first object with weight wt[0], and so on).

You don't really need this kind of tricks, but they are common for dynamic programming. If you don't want to add an extra column for 0 you can omit it, but then you need to add a bunch of checks to make sure you don't try to access memory outside of the allocated area, which makes it a bit harder to test since you have two paths for your logic.

Answer (score 1):

That gives us the best value we can get if we do not select item i. Consider items (value,volume); (2,1), (3,2), (4,5) and a bag of volume 5.

When we are dealing with the third item we can have a value of 4. But if we do not take it, we can have our previous max value which is 5. [Check this video.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8LusJS5-AGo)